# Is it possible to add a blur to the HTML5 dialog backdrop?

Tags: css, html, dialog, css-filters

I'm trying to add a blur effect to the backdrop of a [`dialog`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) (I realise `dialog` currently only has limited support - I'm using `Chrome v66`).

I've tried adding a blur filter to the [`::backdrop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::backdrop) css (no luck), and the [`backdrop-filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter) isn't supported yet.

Anyone know what I should be doing instead?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('mydialog').showModal();
}
```

```css
dialog::backdrop {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .25);
}

/* attempt #1 - using a blur filter */
dialog::backdrop {
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
  -moz-filter: blur(2px);
  -o-filter: blur(2px);
  -ms-filter: blur(2px);
  filter: blur(2px);
}

/* attempt #2 - using backdrop-filter */
dialog::backdrop {
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
}

/* attempt #3 - using an svg */
dialog::backdrop {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100%' height='100%'><defs><filter id='blur'><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation='5' /></filter></defs><rect filter='url(%23blur)' fill='rgba(255,255,255,0.5)' x='0' y='0' width='100%' height='100%'/></svg>");
}
```

```html
Here is some other text that I want blurred.
<dialog id="mydialog">This is the dialog window</dialog>
```

Comment: Have you tried `background-blend-mode`?

Comment: _“I've tried adding a blur filter to the ::backdrop css (no luck)”_ - well of course not, because that backdrop doesn’t _contain_ the stuff you want to blur. `background: rgba(255,0,0,.25)` is the only thing you would be “blurring” with that approach.

Comment: @Ryan, no, haven't tried `background-blend-mode`. Will have a read now, but can't see any `blur` blend modes... can you provide an example?

Answer (score 12):

Use backdrop-filter:

```
dialog::backdrop {
        backdrop-filter: blur(1px);
}
```

Comment: Simple 
Beautiful 

Comment: Not working at all

Answer (score 2):

So not an ideal solution (I'd prefer to use css only), but this is an example workaround using javascript to apply a `.blur` class to the `body`.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('mydialog').showModal();
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].classList.add("blur")
}
```

```css
dialog::backdrop {
  background: rgba(255,0,0,.25);
}
.blur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
  -moz-filter: blur(2px);
  -o-filter: blur(2px);
  -ms-filter: blur(2px);
  filter: blur(2px);
}
```

```html
Here is some other text that I want blurred.
<dialog id="mydialog">This is the dialog window</dialog>
```